# MATLAB: How to demodulate a STREAMING audio file rather than a saved audio file?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, audio-streaming

I wrote the simple MATLAB program below to demodulate an audio signal that has previously been frequency modulated with a carrier frequency of 10000 Hz. The program records the frequency-modulated signal, stores it on disc (for possible later use), then retrieves and demodulates it. Now I would like to be able to demodulate (and display) the signal continuously as it streams in, without first having to store it. Any suggestions on how to modify the MATLAB code below?

```
% FM Demodulate an Audio File June 5, 2018

%% Record the previously frequency-modulated signal for a few seconds.
Fs = 44100; % Sample frequency of the sound wave
duration = 5; % Duration of recording in seconds
recObj = audiorecorder(Fs,16,1); % Sets up the recording conditions

pause(4) % Pause before recording 
disp('Start recording.')
recordblocking(recObj,duration);
disp('End of recording.');

%% Store data in double-precision array.
filename = 'RecordedWave.wav';
myRecording = getaudiodata(recObj);
Fs = get(recObj, 'SampleRate');
audiowrite(filename,myRecording,Fs) % Writes the y and Fs as a .wav file

%% Read it back into memory
[y,Fs] = audioread(filename); 
% The above statement reads the stored .wav file and loads the y vector
% as well as the stored value of Fs for that .wav file.

%% Demodulate the recorded high-frequency FM sound signal
z = demod(y,10000,44100,'fm');

%% Make and then apply a bandpass filter
filterOrder = 2;
fcutlow = 2;
fcuthigh= 10;
[b,a] = butter(filterOrder,[fcutlow,fcuthigh]/(Fs/2),'bandpass');
z_filtered = filter(b,a,z); % Apply the bandpass filter

%% Plot the demodulated and filtered signal
figure
t_sec = (0:1/Fs:duration-1/Fs);  % here is the vector of time
plot(t_sec,z_filtered)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated your post with some tags that explains which language you're using, and update your post with which framework/library/APIs you're using for that language. In absence of that knowledge: you need a buffer to do any DSP, and a common approach is to store samples in a buffer of length X, do your work, empty it out and fill it with new samples. Some libraries do that buffer work for you and all you need to do is write the code that has to run every time slice.

Comment: MPK - I updated my post according to your suggestions. Thanks. JF

Comment: Did you have a look at using https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/gs/real-time-audio-in-matlab.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the audioDeviceReader and audioDeviceWriter objects that allow you to acquire data and playback data in chunks. This way if your algorithm is fast enough you can do the processing in real-time.